# HTTP Basic Auth w/ Cordova/Meteor Application

Tags: cordova, meteor, basic-authentication

I'm in the middle of building a meteor application and am trying to get hot-code pushes working on my cordova mobile builds, but am running into an issue connecting to a meteor application that's behind HTTP basic auth.

I've deployed a meteor server to say https://XXX.domain.com, which I'v protected with HTTP basic auth (username:password). When I load https://XXX.domain.com in my desktop browser, I quickly get prompted for the HTTP Basic auth info. Once entered, I'm allowed full access to the meteor application and everything works great. I even see the following in my console, so I know it's working.

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://XXX.domain.com/app.manifest
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache NoUpdate event
```

Also, when I make server changes, I can see the appcache noticing the change, downloading the app in the background and reloading. So I'm pretty sure this all works from a non-cordova context.

However, when I try to switch to cordova builds (ios or android) I get the following errors in the console (xcode console).

```
2015-02-04 12:12:34.994 Bolt[634:216275] METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Error reading version file Error: Failed to resolve entry: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/892CDCD7-894C-4CC2-A308-CC19A67BC0E3/Library/NoCloud/meteor/version
2015-02-04 12:12:34.994 Bolt[634:216275] METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Couldn't load from the manifest, falling back to the bundled assets.
```

which looks to me like the bundled app can't connect to the mobile server that I pass in at build time.

```
meteor build DIR --server https://username:password@XXX.domain.com
```

or

```
meteor build DIR --server username:password@XXX.domain.com:443
```

I've tried a number of different ways to reference the server and can't seem to get it right. Is there a way to pass HTTP basic auth to the mobile server connection? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Thanks for any help!

J.

Comment: Why are you using HTTP auth when Meteor has built-in SRP authentication? Meteor doesn't even use HTTP for data transfer by default.

Comment: Where can I read more about SRP auth to see if it suits my needs?

Comment: [Here's some info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) about the Secure Remote Password protocol. [Here's the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_api) on Meteor's accounts API, which uses SRP.

Comment: I read about SRP over the weekend and while that does look like a neat way to exchange passwords between the client and the server securely, this doesn't protect the HTTP assets (JS, CSS, HTML) that Meteor serves up. I guess what I'm saying is that I'm not using this auth to authenticate users to my site, but rather to protect the assets on a meteor site that is still in development / unreleased. From what I read SRP won't help with this issue, right?